# How to bind validation error message from server to corresponding `EditText` on layout?

Tags: android, json, validation

I have next validation response from server (generated by `symfony2`)

```
{
    "code":400,
    "message":"Validation Failed",
    "errors":{
        "children":{
            "username":{
                "errors": [ "This value should not be blank." ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can parse this `JSON` response, get the object of class `ValidationResponse`:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ValidationResponse{
    ...
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String userNameError;
}
```

Now I have in layout `EditText mEditTextUserName`, and `userNameError = "This value should not be blank."`

I don't wanna check all fields in `ValidationResponse` for error messages with tons of `if else` constructions

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(validationResponse.getUserNameError())){
            mEditTextUserName.setError(validationResponse.getUserNameError());
            mEditTextUserName.requestFocus();
}
```

This will bring a lot of unnedeed code in my project, for "simple" form fields validation.

As alternative,
I can create

```
HashMap<String, EditText> editFields;
...
editFields.put("username", mEditTextUserName);
...
// send request, parse validation response
((EdiText)editFields.get("username")).setError(validationError.getUserNameError());
```

But I don't like this solution.

Is there a way to bind validation error message from `JSON` from server to `EditText` error using `annotations` or other language construction?

Comment: Just to be clear, you can have tons of `EditText` fields with single ValidationResponse per field?

Comment: I have exact count of EditText fields as "children"'s count in ValidationResponse. editTextUserName = "username", editTextPassword = "password", etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my humble opinion you are complicating yourself work and waste time on this issue. If you have exact number of `EditText`s corresponding to `JSON` fields then there is no point to figure out some sophisticated implementation. At the end it could make your code event more difficult to read.

You have to keep references to all your `EditText` views anyway, right? Alternative with `HashMap` does not give you any benefit. The only thing you could do is creating method for checking `EditText` and error value.

```
private void setEditTextAndValidate(EditText editText, String errorMsg) {
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(errorMsg)){
            editText.setError(errorMsg);
            editText.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

and then call

```
setEditTextAndValidate(mEditTextUserName, validationResponse.getUserNameError());
setEditTextAndValidate(mEditTextPassword, validationResponse.getPasswordError());
```

Once again, it's just my opinion that I would like to share. Maybe there are frameworks that will do it for you, but is it worth to you, I doubt.

Comment: it's a good one. I'm looking for more clear solution, where I can process validation response and pass errors to EditText's in a for-each loop for ex.

Comment: I would understand this approach if you iterate through list of responses and take just username and apply to different EditTexts. But you have to explicitly call response methods and assign to specific views. It has to be coded somewhere. Looking for some generic code with binding configuration will create lots of complicated code. Maybe you will separate it somewhere(moving to package) but it's not worth it.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. @Loop please do you think you could give me your opinion on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598696/recommended-way-order-to-read-data-from-a-webservice-parse-that-data-and-inse